# Setup Qt4 and PyQt for Python 2.6 under MacOS

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, pyqt4

I downloaded Qt4 from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/ and installed it.

Using MacPorts I tried to install PyQt as a binding for Python 2.6.1 (which is installed by default in MacOS X Snow Leopard) using both these two lines:

```
sudo port install py-pyqt4
sudo port install py26-pyqt4
```

Obviously that didnt work. If I try importing some Qt4-Modules in the interactive python-shell, I get the following error:

```
>>> import PyQt4.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore
```

What did I do wrong? How do I get Python with Qt4 and PyQt running?

Comment: Of course. Thank you, I fixed that. Makes no difference though.

Comment: Did you try to install the official distribution from Riverbank? http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download. See also:http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/installation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself: PyQt4 was installed correctly and so was Qt4. However, PyQt was installed in the MacPort's installation of python, not in the system's python-installation. To change the installation that will start when executing "python" I selected python26 using macports:

```
sudo port select python python26
```